# bound eigenvalues with supremumsnorm

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a symetric ($n \times n$) matrix and D be the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and O be the orthogonal matrix such that $A = O^TDO$

Is it possible to somehow bound the eigenvalues with A like

$\max_{i=1...n} |\lambda_i| \leq ||A||_\infty$?

Comment: What does $\|A\|_\infty$ denote?  Is it the largest norm of entries in $A$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$, you have that
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \ge \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}=\frac{|\lambda|\|v\|}{\|v\|} = |\lambda|
$$

So,  any matrix norm obtained from a vector norm in this way satisfies $\|A\| \ge |\lambda|$ and, consequently, $\|A\| \ge \max_i \{|\lambda_i|\}$.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: There is a possible meaning of $\|A\|_\infty$ that wouldn’t match this answer.  Sometimes this represents the largest of the absolute values of the entries in $A$.  In this case, the upper bound should be $n\|A\|_\infty$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I never came across that definition, but thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes $\|A\|_\infty$ denotes the supremum of the absolute value of the entries in $A$.  (This definition sometimes shows up in symbolic algebra and isn't a matrix norm in the sense of Pierre Carre's answer).

In this case, the upper bound is $n\|A\|_\infty$ since if $v_i$ is the largest entry of $v$ in absolute value, then
$$
|\lambda||v_i|=|(Av)_i|=\left|\sum_j A_{ij}v_j\right|\leq \sum|A_{ij}||v_j|\leq n\|A\|_\infty|v_i|.
$$

Note that this bound is attained when $A$ is the matrix of all $1$'s (or any multiple of this matrix).

Comment: thank you very much. Where do we get $v_i$ in the last inequality?

Comment: $v_i$ was assumed to be the largest component of $v$ in absolute value, we have $|v_j|\leq|v_i|$ in the last inequality.

Comment: oh i see thanks! could you maybe have a look at my answer? im quite confused since my solution would give a rate like $|\lambda|\leq n^{\frac{1}{2}}||A||_\infty$ but you mentioned that your bound is sharp... but i don´t find my mistake :/